# Triple $\langle F, G, \varphi\rangle: X\to A$, what does this notation mean?

Tags: category-theory

In Mac Lane's book "Category Theory for Working Mathematician", there is this definition:

What does the notation "$\langle F, G, \varphi\rangle: X\to A$" mean? Is this standard notation, or is there another way to write it?

Thanks for any help.
[image]

Comment: The paragraph you joined is the definition of the notation in question.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there any reason for the "upper half arrow" $X\to A$ notation?

Comment: @yoyostein: just to distinguish it from an arrow that might indicate a simple functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph you joined is the definition of the notation in question.

A standard notation for adjunction of functors $F$ and $G$ is $\ F\dashv G$, which indicates the existence of such a natural isomorphism $\varphi$.